# Getting camera focal length in Android API 21 and above

Tags: android, camera

In Android API 21, the Camera class seems to be deprecated. What is the replacement for getting the current focal length of the camera if I don't want to manually set it? How likely is something along the lines of character.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)[0]) to work on the average phone? (character is an object of CameraCharacteristics)